# How to find out the keys of a dictionary with maximum number of common values?

Tags: python

Suppose, there is a dictionary like

```py
my_dict = {'A': {'5', '7', '9', '3'},
           'B': {'4', '8','3'},
           'C': {'5', '3', '2', '9'},
           'D': {'1','6', '8','3'},
           'E': {'4','3','5'}}
```

Now the output should be like {A,C} because they have most number of common values.

Comment: What have you tried? Any thoughts, any ideas? Please show us the effort you've put into solving the problem so far.

Comment: Without a solution attempt from you, the responses will be few and more on the critical side.

Comment: You also haven't specified everything about what you're looking for. Have you thought about corner cases? What if two pairs of keys are tied for the most items in common? For that matter, what if those two pairs have a key in common, such that a trio of keys all have the most items in common?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
dct = {'A': {'5', '7', '9', '3'}, 'B': {'4', '8','3'}, 'C': {'5', '3', '2', '9'}, 'D': {'1','6', '8','3'}, 'E': {'4','3','5'}}
ans = [None, None]
mx = 0

for i in dct:
    for j in dct:
        if i != j and len(dct[i].intersection(dct[j])) > mx:
            ans = [i, j]
            mx = len(dct[i].intersection(dct[j]))
```

As there are sets contained, to find number of common elements, we have `intersection` method.

```
>>> ans
['A', 'C']
```

Although, its worth noting that this code would always produce a pair. If you want more number of elements, the number of loops is going to increase accordingly.

Comment: It's not generally a good idea to use the names of builtin classes (like `dict`) as variable names. Also, note that you're comparing each set pair *twice* with this code.

Comment: @CrazyChucky thanks, I forgot to test the code myself first, so the errors went unnoticed. Fixed now :)